# Can't start Oracle Database XE 18.4 Docker Container

Tags: database, oracle, docker, oracle18c

I'm having this problem after creating the Oracle Database XE 18.4 image with WSL2. I'm trying to create a container based on this image and I keep receiving these errors, even though I'm doing exactly the same thing that is asked on [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/deliver-oracle-database-18c-express-edition-in-containers) tutorial provided by Oracle.
The errors show up when I try to create the container and turn it on for the first time

```
sed: can't read /etc/oratab: No such file or directory
/opt/oracle/runOracle.sh: line 194: /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c: No such file or directory
grep: /etc/oratab: No such file or directory
/opt/oracle/checkDBStatus.sh: line 18: oraenv: No such file or directory
#####################################
########### E R R O R ###############
DATABASE SETUP WAS NOT SUCCESSFUL!
Please check output for further info!
########### E R R O R ###############
#####################################
The following output is now a tail of the alert.log:
tail: cannot open '/opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/*/*/trace/alert*.log' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining
```

I would like to know what on earth could I do to solve these errors and get this database running. As a matter of fact, I can't verify if these files mentioned in the log exist because I can't even connect to this container as it remains on for around 5 seconds due to these errors.
I'm using Docker on Windows integrated with WSL2.
My Docker installation info is:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.12
 Version:           20.10.5
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Built:             Tue Mar  2 20:14:53 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.5
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       363e9a8
  Built:            Tue Mar  2 20:15:47 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.4
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc93
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
```

Comment: My guess is you are having a permission problem for the area where you bind /opt/oracle/oradata. Make sure the user 'oracle' inside container can access the filesystem read-write. Check out https://github.com/bjarteb/oracle-apex-ords

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. But am I supposed to see these files if I check the directories through my distro terminal?

Comment: I suspect this could be permission issues on the mapped volumes.  I have used this image: `container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:latest` successfully and it more straightforward than the early directions you followed.  Finally, this blog post was a huge help if you want to build from scratch: https://dbvisit.com/blog/oracle-database-18c-express-edition-getting-started-part-1 However, I just customized the above image in the end.

Answer (score 2):

The `Dockerfile` for XE v18.4.0 is different from all the others in the same repo as it tries to pull the image directly from the oracle web server using https during the container build phase. But the container build phase itself happens inside a container (FROM...) so, in my case, it was failing because it did not have the right internet connectivity (shitty proxy with https problems). The image was created, but it did not contain the database engine.

I have modified the `Dockerfile` inside `OracleDatabase\SingleInstance\dockerfiles\18.4.0` so that istead of using the https origin it does a `COPY` of a (already downloaded) `oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm` inside the image and installs it "locally".

I used as a template the `Dockerfile` of another version, but it's quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

Tucked away in `docker-images\OracleDatabase\SingleInstance\README.md` is the following:

> **IMPORTANT:** You will have to provide the installation binaries of Oracle Database (except for Oracle Database 18c XE) and put them into the `dockerfiles/<version>` folder. You only need to provide the binaries for the edition you are going to install. The binaries can be downloaded from the [Oracle Technology Network](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html), make sure you use the linux link: *Linux x86-64*. The needed file is named *linuxx64_<version>_database.zip*. You also have to make sure to have internet connectivity for yum. Note that you must not uncompress the binaries. The script will handle that for you and fail if you uncompress them manually!

If you download the OracleXE RPM from https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html and copy it into the version directory as described in the doc, when building the Oracle XE docker image, it seems to do a full install of Oracle XE using the downloaded RPM.

If you skip the manual download of the RPM before building the Docker image, it seems the container will be built, but it tries to do the download when run, which for me at least, didn't work.

Once the Docker image has been built, a container can be started using:

```
docker run --name oraclexe \
  -p 51521:1521 \
  -p 55500:5500 \
  -v [HOST_PATH]:/opt/oracle/oradata \
  -e ORACLE_PWD=mysecurepassword \
  -e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8 \
  oracle/database:18.4.0-xe
```

Where `HOST_PATH` is the path to the local directory that Oracle will store the database in.